# "Operation not permitted" error when run the "vagrant up" and mount NFS shared folders on mac

Tags: macos, vagrant, virtualbox

I spent hours working on the issue shown below in the error message and cannot find a similar issue by google searching. I mean the error of "Operation not permitted @ rb_sysopen...".

I am using "Vagrant 2.2.16" and "virtualbox 6.1.26" on MacOS Big Sur. I added the "nfsd" to full disk access but it does not help.

```
Installing Virtualbox Guest Additions 6.1.26 - guest version is 5.2.34

Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.2.8
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.2.34
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
[default] A Virtualbox Guest Additions installation was found but no tools to rebuild or start them.
Got different reports about installed GuestAdditions version:
Virtualbox on your host claims:   5.2.8
VBoxService inside the vm claims: 5.2.34
Going on, assuming VBoxService is correct...
...
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Starting.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the VirtualBox Guest Additions kernel
modules.  This may take a while.
VirtualBox Guest Additions: To build modules for other installed kernels, run
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup <version>
VirtualBox Guest Additions: or
VirtualBox Guest Additions:   /sbin/rcvboxadd quicksetup all
VirtualBox Guest Additions: Building the modules for kernel 4.15.0-88-generic.
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-88-generic
Unmounting Virtualbox Guest Additions ISO from: /mnt
==> default: Checking for guest additions in VM...
==> default: Configuring and enabling network interfaces...
==> default: Installing NFS client...
==> default: Exporting NFS shared folders...
==> default: Preparing to edit /etc/exports. Administrator privileges will be required...
==> default: Mounting NFS shared folders...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.16/gems/vagrant-2.2.16/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:608:in `read': Operation not permitted @ rb_sysopen - /Users/frank/Documents/work/MyProject/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/creator_uid (Errno::EPERM)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.16/gems/vagrant-2.2.16/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:608:in `read'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.16/gems/vagrant-2.2.16/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:608:in `uid'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.16/gems/vagrant-2.2.16/plugins/providers/virtualbox/provider.rb:92:in `state'
...
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.16/gems/vagrant-2.2.16/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:201:in `action'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.16/gems/vagrant-2.2.16/lib/vagrant/batch_action.rb:86:in `block (2 levels) in run'
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.16/gems/vagrant-2.2.16/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:608:in `read': Operation not permitted @ rb_sysopen - /Users/frank/Documents/work/MyProject/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/creator_uid (Errno::EPERM)
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.16/gems/vagrant-2.2.16/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:608:in `read'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.16/gems/vagrant-2.2.16/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:608:in `uid'
    from /opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.16/gems/vagrant-2.2.16/plugins/providers/virtualbox/provider.rb:92:in `state'
...
/opt/vagrant/embedded/gems/2.2.16/gems/vagrant-2.2.16/lib/vagrant/machine.rb:608:in `read': Operation not permitted @ rb_sysopen - /Users/frank/Documents/work/MyProject/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/creator_uid (Errno::EPERM)
...loop this part...
```

Comment: I am still digging and it seems to be related with using ruby gem to access something and it has permission issue

Answer (score 0):

Actually my colleague saved my day. The walk around is to not work under the folder of Documents on Mac folder system, instead creating folders outside of Documents folder. This folder has some permission issue, even though not knowing specifically the details about the root cause yet.

I tried to reinstall a lot of things and deal with the permission issues and none of them works.

A small trick saves a day of me. Hope you can benefit from this too.

Comment: Thank you! I have been stuck on this for 2 days! This solved the issue <3!